# The use of "apply to" in a sentence

Tags: grammatical-number, word-order

On page 155 of his 1976 book, The Uses of Enchantment: The Meaning and Importance of Fairy Tales, author Bruno Bettelheim writes:

"Unfortunately, some moderns reject fairy tales because they **apply to this literature standards** which are totally inappropriate.

Fırst I thought it talked about applying some literature standards, but then I realized the singular/plural disagreement. As it writes "**apply to this** literature **standards**" Does it mean to "**apply** standards **to** this literature"?

Comment: What singular/plural disagreement?

Comment: "This literature standards." It is between "this" and "standards".

Comment: Ah, as you surmise, it means "apply standards to this literature". *Literature* is the object of the preposition *to*, not an attributive noun modifying standards. That makes *this* an determinative applying to *literature*.

Comment: The author is Bruno Bettleheim.

Comment: Actually, I had asked another question about a quote from the same book. Then, an editor edited my question and added the name of the book and of the author. (In my original question, I hadn't added the names) So when I was writing this question, I just copied the first part from that question which was edited, only changed the number of the page. I just wanted to make it clear that I didn't write the autors name wrong. Still, I should have checked before copying it. Thank you for letting me know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

'this' belongs to Literature, so there is no singular/plural disagreement.

Standards are being 'app[lied] to this literature'

The assertion being that when you view fairy tales according to modern day standards it makes them appear inferior in some way.

Comment: Your answer is very explanatory, Gary. Thank you for your support.

Comment: Nice to be able to help, thanks for the feedback @kindercountry